# how to set gtk to c/c++ netbeans IDE?

Tags: gcc, netbeans, gtk

I want to write GTK+ programs in Netbeans(version 6.9) in Ubuntu. Now I can compile GTK+ program via gcc compiler. But when write programs in Netbeans IDE, I can't build programs. The compiler sends me this error:

```
main.cpp:9:17: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory'
```

I searched this error in google and pass steps in [this](http://zetcode.com/articles/netbeanscdevelopment/) site, but still it dose not work. I also pass following steps for solving my problem:

1. Set ProjectProperties/Build/C(C++) Compiler/additional Options to `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0`
2. Set ProjectProperties/Build/Linker/Additional Options to `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --libs`
3. Add ProjectProperties/Build/C(C++) Compiler/Include Directories and Tools/Options/cc++ /Code assistance to following headers:

   ```
   /usr/include/atk-1.0
   /usr/include/pango-1.0
   /usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/
   /usr/include/glib-2.0
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
   /usr/include/freetype2
   /usr/include/libpng12
   /usr/include/gtk-2.0
   /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/include
   /usr/include/cairo
   /usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0
   /usr/include/pixman-1
   ```

These steps don't solve my problem. IDE also draws a yellow line in the `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` line of code. How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup a C GTK+ Project in Netbeans

1. Create a C Project (not a C++).
2. Open the Project Properties window.
3. Go to "Build -> C Compiler".
4. In "Include Directories", add ALL the paths for GTK+ include requirements:

   (assuming The root is in "C:/libs/c++/gtk"):

   C:/libs/c++/gtk/include;C:/libs/c++/gtk/include/atk-1.0;C:/libs/c++/gtk/include/cairo;C:/libs/c++/gtk/include/fontconfig;C:/libs/c++/gtk/include/freetype2;C:/libs/c++/gtk/include/gail-1.0;C:/libs/c++/gtk/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0;C:/libs/c++/gtk/include/gio-win32-2.0;C:/libs/c++/gtk/include/glib-2.0;C:/libs/c++/gtk/include/gtk-2.0;C:/libs/c++/gtk/include/libpng14;C:/libs/c++/gtk/include/pango-1.0;C:/libs/c++/gtk/include/pixman-1;C:/libs/c++/gtk/lib;C:/libs/c++/gtk/lib/glib-2.0/include;C:/libs/c++/gtk/lib/gtk-2.0/include
5. In "Additional Options", set:

   $$(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0)
6. Go to "Build -> Linker".
7. In "Additional Library Directories", set the same values as in Point 4 (the "Include Directories" content).
8. In "Additional Options", set the same as in Point 5 (the "Build -> C Compiler -> Additional Options" content).

After this, your GTK+ project in Netbeans should be Compilable/Runnable. Working in Windows 7, Netbeans 7.3.

Comment: what C/C++ compiler are you using? (e.g. MinGW, Cygwin, etc...)